# Getting simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)

Tags: python, json

URL: https://www.ted.com/talks/emily_balcetis_why_some_people_find_exercise_harder_than_others/transcript.json?language=en

```
import json
import requests
url = "https://www.ted.com/talks/emily_balcetis_why_some_people_find_exercise_harder_than_others/transcript.json?language=en"
data = requests.get(url).json()
```

Actually, I am parsing around 100+ URLs, but sometimes I am getting the error, sometimes I am not.
For Example, this URL was not throwing this error 1 hour ago, now it's throwing.

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tedcrawler.py", line 89, in <module>
    EnglishTranscript(url)
  File "tedcrawler.py", line 58, in EnglishTranscript
    data = requests.get(url).json()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 896, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 516, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)`

Solved : The Error is due Too Many Requests StatusCode 429

Comment: I am not getting any errors. Post the complete code. Maybe something else is happening.

Comment: Also could you post full error stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you're getting rate limited or some other server side errors. You can try checking if status code is `status_ok` then parse json.

```
import json
import requests

url = "https://www.ted.com/talks/emily_balcetis_why_some_people_find_exercise_harder_than_others/transcript.json?language=hi"

data = requests.get(url)
print data.status_code
if data.status_code == 200:
     print data.json()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The Status Code is 429, which is "Too many HTTP Requests".

Comment: Ah! Cool . `sleep`  your code  for 5-10 min to overcome this.

Comment: I am sleeping for 60 seconds after each URL hit. Let's check if it works otherwise will increase the time. Thanks again.